# Trying to set up Django, but receiving error in cmd

Tags: python, django, cmd

I'm in the process of learning about django and the different possibilities that it brings, however I am unable to go through the first few steps that I found in pretty much every tutorial.

I successfully installed django-2.2.6, pytz-2019.3 and sqlparse-0.3.0. I then set up the correct directory to my working folder, I used `django-admin startproject mysite` and finally `python manage.py runserver`.

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

When I try to connect to the local machine on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ it loads up just fine, but then I get this output in cmd and it will not let me do anything else:

```
[26/Oct/2019 23:29:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[26/Oct/2019 23:29:47] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[26/Oct/2019 23:29:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[26/Oct/2019 23:29:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[26/Oct/2019 23:29:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
Not Found: /favicon.ico
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50150)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arivald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Arivald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Arivald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Arivald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Arivald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Arivald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

I disabled the antivirus to be sure that it doesn't interfere with anything, but that did not help.

Could someone please help me out as I am unable to proceed from here.

Edit:
So far I have uninstalled python and installed the newest version (3.8.0 at the time of writing). I created new virtual environments and installed django inside. I tried disabling my antivirus and using a different browser. I am still receiving the same error that does not allow me to continue typing commands into cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like this is a bug in Python:

https://bugs.python.org/issue27682

It has been fixed. If you upgrade to the latest version of Python 3.7, it should be fixed: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-375/

Good luck!

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of Python, but the problem still persists

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't look like you're using a `venv` either. Can you verify that you're on Python 3.7.5 by typing `python --version` or `python3 --version`, depending on how you invoke it at the command line?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I upgraded python to the newest version which is 3.8.0 and uninstalled the previous 3.7.x. I have also created a virtual environment, installed django there and tried everything again. Same error output in cmd not allowing me to proceed.

Comment: Huh, I figured that bug was the error, as others had reported the upgrade working. Sorry it didn't help you out!